# Prometheus Alert Overwrite

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to set up alert rules on Prometheus. My app already has an alert rule for CPUWarning.

```yaml
- name: General
  rules:
  - alert: CPU_Warning
    expr: ssCpuSystem >= 70
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: Host cpu over 70%
```

but I need to update this logic for some specific instances

```yaml
- name: General
  rules:
  - alert: CPU_A5_Warning
    expr: ssCpuSystem{intance="A5"} >= 90
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: Host cpu over 90%
```

Does anyone know how? I know theres a [Lalab's solution](https://github.com/lablabs/prometheus-alert-overrider) everywhere on Google but I need a way that doesn't implement a new tool or a third party. Please help, Thank you.

I tried to to add both alerts as above but It doesn't seem to work as I need.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want. Have you considered changing expression in first alert rule to `ssCpuSystem{intance!="A5"} >= 70`?